# Regarding error thrown by sizeof(class) usage in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sizeof

When I compile my project in C++, the following error is thrown by MSVC :

> error #94: the size of an array must be greater than zero

The error is thrown in the following line on doing sizeof :

```
if (sizeof (MyNamespace::MyClass) == 60)
```

MyClass is defined thus :

```
class MyClass: public ParentClass
{
    public:
        MyClass( void *pCreate, int a, int b, bool c) :
              ParentClass( pCreate, a, b, c ) {}

        virtual inline void myFunc ( ) 
        {
            //something
        }
    private:
        virtual ~MyClass(){};

        /**
        * Copy assignment. Intentionally made private and not implemented to prohibit usage (noncopyable stereotype)
        */
        MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&);
};
```

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong? Even if sizeof returns zero size, why is it a compiler error?

Comment: Is there an array in the ParentClass?

Comment: The size of each class has to be at least byte, even if it is empty, to tell apart 2 members of it for example in an array(if it where 0 they would get the same address). Is the error thrown at exact this line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is caused when you take the `sizeof` of a class that's only *declared* at that point. E.g. `class MyClass; const size_t error = sizeof(MyClass);`.

Note that it doesn't matter whether the class is fully defined later: the definition must precede the `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

This error is most likely caused by a forward declaration. At the line where you use sizeof, the compiler needs to know the definition of your class MyClass, that is you must have #included the header file for it